# With an VB Scritp How to check if an excel file is already opened and close it without saving it.

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have the following code. It copies a sheet from one workbook to another workbook. It works fine if both files are closed. I want to modify this code, to first check if both files are opened, close them without saving any changes, and finally perform the same that I have by now.

```
' Create Excel object
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

' Open the source workbook
Set SOURCE = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("Path\Source.xls")


' Open the destination workbook
Set DEST = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:Path\Destination.xlsx")


objExcel.Visible = False


' Select the range on source Sheet1 you want to copy 
SOURCE.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:AZ2500").Copy

' Paste it on Destiny Sheet1, starting at A1
DEST.Worksheets("Sheet").Range("A1").PasteSpecial


' Save and close workbooks

DEST.save
DEST.close
SOURCE.close
```

Comment: Remove `DEST.save` and amend the pre-last line to `DEST.close False`

Comment: Bur, in case that the files are closed, I want them to be saved and closed.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will check if Excel is open, and if it is, check for your source and destination workbooks, closing them without saving them if they're open.  After which it opens the files, and sets the range in Destination to the range in Source.

Given that the code is purely to set the same range every time though, I can't help but think you would be as well to simply open the Source workbook then just save it as the destination and overwrite the existing destination file.

Let me know if you need any further explanation of how this works.

```
Option Explicit

Dim oExcel, oWorkbook

' Check if Excel is open
On Error Resume Next
Set oExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application") ' If Excel is open this will set a reference to it
On Error Goto 0
If Not IsObject(oExcel) Then
    ' Excel wasn't running, create an instance
    Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
End If

' Check any open workbooks in the Excel instance
If oExcel.Workbooks.Count > 0 Then
    For Each oWorkbook In oExcel.Workbooks
        If oWorkbook.Path = "Path\Source.xls" Or oWorkbook.Path = "Path\Destination.xlsx" Then
            oWorkbook.Close True    ' closes workbook without saving changes
        End If
    Next
End If

' Open the source workbook
Set SOURCE = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("Path\Source.xls")

' Open the destination workbook
Set DEST = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("Path\Destination.xlsx")

oExcel.Visible = False

' Set the destination range to the source range
DEST.Worksheets("Sheet").Range("A1:AZ2500") = SOURCE.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:AZ2500")

' Save and close workbooks
DEST.Save
DEST.Close
SOURCE.Close

Set oExcel = Nothing ' drop the reference to excel object
```

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for the help. The code didn´t work, at least as a VBscript. An "Undefined variable" (for source) is shown.

Comment: Hi Jose, That will be because I added `Option Explicit` to the start of the code. It makes variable declarations mandatory and is useful to make sure you keep track of what you are using. You'll need to add `Dim SOURCE ` and `Dim DEST` statements to the code to declare them and then the undefined variable issue will be resolved.